# Regex that matches a number with commas for every three digits

Tags: python, regex

How would you write a regex that matches a number with commas for every three digits? It must match the following: '42', '1,234', and '6,368,745'.

but not the following: '12,34,567' (which has only two digits between the commas), '1234' (which lacks commas).

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but those were only for solutions where the string passed to the regex was one of those numbers. I was wondering what the best way to do it if the regex is passed the whole string '42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234'.

I managed to do it by splitting the string first and then looping through it like below:

```
regexsplit = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$')
splitstring = string.split()
matches = []

for num in splitstring:
    if regexsplit.search(num) is not None:
        matches.append(regexsplit.search(num).group())

print matches
```

First, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing that code. Secondly, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without splitting the string and using the .findall() method. I know you'd no longer be able to use the ^ and $ to anchor the beginning and end, so I've done:

```
regexnosplit = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)')
matches2 = []

for groups in regexnosplit.findall(string):
    print groups[0]
```

However, I'm obviously still getting '12', '34,567', '123', '4' returned, so I'm guessing I need to pass a more robust regex, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: You need to ensure that the match ends at the end of the number - look into word boundaries and negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
^((?:\d{1,3},(?:\d{3},)*\d{3})|(?:\d{1,3}))$
```

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/65nMlq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, trying to find the unwanted patterns:

```
import re

s = '42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234'

rgx = re.compile(',[0-9]{1,2},|[0-9]{4,}')
nums = [x for x in s.split() if not rgx.search(x)]

print nums  # ['42', '1,234', '6,368,745']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whitespace boundary's to match just the properly formatted
thousands place comma numbers.

`(?<!\S)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?!\S)`

Explained

```
 (?<! \S )            # Whitespace boundary
 \d{1,3}              # Required 1-3 digits
 (?: , \d{3} )*       # Optional comma + 3 digits, 0 to many times
 (?! \S )             # Whitespace boundary
```

Test target `42 1,234 6,368,745 12,34,567 1234`

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 2 ) 
42  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 3 , len 5 ) 
1,234  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 9 , len 9 ) 
6,368,745
```

Answer (score 0):

The one that worked for me:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*$')
```

You can check here: https://regex101.com/r/TsTNQm/1